# Ohms Law Voltage/Potential Difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Three 2.0 Ω resistors are connected in series to a 12 V battery. What is the potential difference across each resistor?
�
This question requires Ohms law because V is needed right?
So I would use I = V/R
and use Req = r1 + r2 + r3... 
then does I(Current) = 12?

so 12 = V/6 
Im confused.

Comment: $R_\mathrm{eq}$ looks right.  How did you calculate the current to arrive at 12 A?  (Assuming you do mean I(Current) = 12 Amp.)

Comment: The 12V battery is not the current so how would I calculate it? I = v/r but I dont have v? the correct answer is 4V for the potential resistance. @garyp

Comment: It looks like you have a battery providing a voltage, and the resistance across the battery.  You've also demonstrated that you know Ohm's Law.  Maybe you should draw a sketch with  the three separate resistors replaced by the one equivalent resistor.  See if it helps to look at that sketch.

Comment: The 12V battery is not the current so how would I calculate it? I = v/r but I dont have v? the correct answer is 4V for the potential resistance. @garyp I mean I got the current to be 2, voltage to be 12, and resistance to be 6, but the correct answer says the potential difference is 4V? Is it 4 because since the V = 12 and it is asking for potential difference across each resister and there are 3, so 12/3 = 4V? lol oh... my bad

Comment: Your analysis is correct for this highly symmetric case.  All of the resistors have the same value.  Suppose the three resistors were $R_1 = 1\;\Omega$,   $R_2 = 2\;\Omega$,   $R_3 = 3\;\Omega$.  Can you calculate the voltage across $R_1$?  Doing this exercise provides a method to solve these problems that will work in more general situations than does your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the three resistors are connected in series, the total effective resistance is $3\times 2\Omega=6\Omega$ and the current is $I=U/R_{\rm tot}=12/6{\rm A}=2{\rm A}$, and the potential across each resistor is $IR=2\times 2{\rm V}=4{\rm V}$.

However, an easy way to do it is, since we know in this case the current through each resistor is the same, so the potential $U$ must be divided evenly, which means the potential across each resistor is $12{\rm V}/3=4{\rm V}$.

Comment: Careful: this sounds like a homework problem.